# Checking if a file is in a S3 bucket using the s3cmd

Tags: if-statement, amazon-s3

I having a program that successfully uploads all of the files that I need. I have new files everyday that I need to upload. After I have uploaded the files I no longer need them and thus am not looking to sync them.

I am curious if there is a way to check if given a path and file name if that exists within S3 using the s3cmd.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the ls command in s3cmd to know if a file is present or not in S3.

Bash code

```
path=$1
count=`s3cmd ls $path | wc -l`

if [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "exist"
else
        echo "do not exist"
fi
```

Usage: ./s3_exist.sh s3://foo/bar.txt

Edit:

As cocoatomo pointed out in comments, `s3cmd ls $path` lists all file that **begins with** `$path`. A safer approach would be to use `s3cmd info $path` and check the exit code.

New Bash code

```
path=$1
s3cmd info $path >/dev/null 2>&1

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "exist"
else
    echo "do not exist"
fi
```

Comment: So count is the number of files within that directory, I understand that. I however have not ran across the -gt part and cannot find anything when I tried googling it, would you mind explaining that part?

Comment: Count the number of files that match a given path and filename. Since S3 doesn't support duplicate filenames, this count will be either 0 (file not present) or 1 (file present). "-gt" stands for "greater than". You can also do [[ $count -eq 1 ]] if this is more explicit for you. For more details about conditional expression in Bash: [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Comment: The first argument of "s3cmd ls" means a bucket name or a prefix string following a bucket name, not a file name. Since "s3cmd ls s3://foo/b" lists "s3://foo/bar.txt" if exists, "$count -gt 0" does not show whether s3://foo/b exists or not.

Comment: Unfortunately one cannot trust the exit codes of `s3cmd` at all; even the version shipped in Ubuntu 14.04 universe can return 0 for `s3cmd put` even if the server's network is not connected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that bar.txt and bar.txt.bak exist in a bucket s3://foo, "s3cmd ls s3://foo/bar.txt" shows a following output.

```
$ s3cmd ls s3://foo/bar.txt
2013-11-11 11:11    5   s3://foo/bar.txt
2013-11-11 11:11    5   s3://foo/bar.txt.bak
```

Since we should remove 2nd line from the command result, we use "awk" command to filter unnecessary lines.

```
$ filename=s3://foo/bar.txt
$ s3cmd ls ${filename} | awk "\$4 == \"${filename}\" { print \$4 }"
2013-11-11 11:11    5   s3://foo/bar.txt
```

Finally, we build up all commands.

```
filename=s3://foo/bar.txt
count=$(s3cmd ls ${filename} | awk "\$4 == \"${filename}\" { print \$4 }" | wc -l)

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "file does not exist"
else
  echo "file exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of AWS CLI, you can use the following code to detect the existence of a file or directory

```
count=$(aws s3 ls $path | wc -l)
if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
  (>&2 echo "$path already exists!")
  return
fi
```

Comment: By using s3cmd, not aws.

Answer (score 0):

We can use s3cmd ls , Take one flag flag_exists true if file is there and false if file is not there.

```
FLAG_EXISTS=false
    for j in $(s3cmd ls s3://abc//abc.txt); do
      if [[ "$j" == "s3://abc//abc.txt" ]]; then
        FLAG_EXISTS=true
        break
      fi
    done
    if [ "$FLAG_EXISTS" = false ]; then
      echo 'file not exists'
    else
      echo 'file exists'
    fi
```

Explanation - Since ls can return many values like if u search for s3cmd ls abc.txt , then it can return values like abc.txt abcd.txt and so on , so looping and checking using if condition if file exists.